# Erratic behaviour of conditional formatting when applied to a cell calculating duration

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

It seems to me that Google Spreadsheets is inconsistent when it comes to conditionally formatting duration-formatted cells. I have made a simple spreadsheet to track how much time I spend at work. I have columns for when I get there, when I leave and one for breaks. I then calculate how long I spent at work and also the cumulative time. When I have spent 8 hrs at work the cell is suppose to be yellow, more than 8 hrs green and less than 8 hrs red.

The problem occurs when the difference (duration) is 0:00:00, sometimes the cell is yellow, sometimes green or red and I can't find any reason why.

[image: Conditional formatting]

[image: Why?]

Comment: Please  change the permession so that anyone with a link can "edit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the accuracy of the likes of `C17-B17-D17-$B$3`. This will rarely return exactly `0`. A fix is to highlight (standard) yellow all of ColumnsE:F (other than the rows presently pale blue), delete the yellow CF rule and adjust the green and red conditions to be very slightly more/less than zero, say green greater than 0.00000000001 and red Less than -0.00000000001.

Comment: Ah, it works! Thanks! I used conditional formatting "Is between" -0.00001 and 0.00001.